# Bash - How do I loop through sub directories and execute this command

Tags: bash, html, markdown

Well, Before I decided to post this I have tried all the solutions provided here that are related to my issue. And I know it's a simple but this is my first time ever dealing with Bash .. so please bear with me a little

I have this Script

```
    FILES=*.html
for f in $FILES
do

  # extension="${f##*.}"
  filename="${f%.*}"
  echo "Converting $f to $filename.md"
  `pandoc $f -t markdown -o $filename.md`
  rm $f
done
```

This script was created to convert a directory full of Html files into markdown equivalents. It uses Pandoc to do the conversion.

The issue is this script will convert the file in the same exact folder only, and I want to convert all the files in subfolders like this:

```
Folder1/Folder2/folder3/index.html
```

So any ideas on how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pretty much the same code but get the full path from `find` and watch out for whitespace

```
find ./path/to/start/from -iname "*.htm*" -exec bash -c 'fn=${1%.*}; sn=${fn##*/}; 
    echo "Converting $1 to $sn.md"; 
    pandoc "$1" -t markdown -o "$fn.md" && rm "$1"
' bash {} \;
```

the construct for `find .....-exec`

```
sh -c `some code here` sh {}
```

feeds the `{}` from `bash`back to `bash -c` as `$1` and lets you play with it from there.

Comment: Wrong tick in the second example

Comment: Didn't work bro, I am on windows using git bash. Please can you descripe in more depth i am totally new to bash scripting

Comment: do you have `find` available?

Comment: `find` appears to be bundled. Am not sure but you could try changing `sh` to `bash` as your shell

Comment: Perhaps `-execdir` would be useful here. Also chaining the `rm` with `&&` so the original is only removed if the conversion succeeds. The `-print0` seems superfluous.`

Comment: Appears there may be an issue with my line-breaking in the post. Edited now.